# How to make a symlink for MySQL?

Tags: symlink

Sorry guys for the silly question but I am really need of help.

Running `df -h` I get

```
/dev/vda1        40G   38G     0 100% /
/dev/sda         99G   60M   94G   1% /mnt/volume-fra1-01
```

I tried to create a symlink between the heaviest folder of my server to the partition with more space.

```
ln -s /var/www/folder1/folder2/folder3.it/ /mnt/volume-fra1-01
```

I have rebooted the server and now when I try to start mysql, this is what I get:

```
 * /etc/init.d/mysql: ERROR: The partition with /var/lib/mysql is too full!
```

How do I give mysql more space from the partition with 100GB?

Please help!!

Comment: Just making a link is not enough, you also need to move data off your root volume or clean up old junk...

Comment: Would it not be a better idea to move the files out of the folder in question and mount /dev/sda at the location of that folder, rather than mounting and linking /mnt/volume-fra1-01?  So /dev/vda1 is still '/', and /dev/sda would be '/var/www/folder1/folder2/folder3.it'?

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to move the data from the old directory to the one that is the target of the symlink.